# Determining whether a value has been consecutively duplicated n times

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am currently working with data which has a structure like the following

| ID | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year4 | Year5 | Year6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | *NA* |
| 2 | 2002 | *NA* | 1001 | 1001 | 9999 | 9999 |
| 3 | 2002 | *NA* | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | *NA* |
| 4 | 3003 | 3003 | 3003 | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | NA | NA |
| 6 | 9999 | 9999 | 9999 | 1001 | 9999 | 9999 |

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 Year1 = c(2002, 2002, 2002, 3003,  1001, 9999),
                 Year2 = c(2002,   NA,   NA, 3003,  1001, 9999),
                 Year3 = c(2002, 1001, 1001, 3003,  1001, 9999),
                 Year4 = c(2002, 1001, 1001,   NA,  1001, 1001),
                 Year5 = c(2002, 9999, 1001,   NA,    NA, 9999),
                 Year6 = c(NA,   9999,   NA,   NA,    NA, 9999))
```

My goal is to construct an additional variable `duplicated_from_end` which indicates whether, for each observation, the most recent non-missing value (i.e., the non-missing value with the highest year) has been duplicated at least *n* times (say, *n = 3* in this example) consecutively. For instance, for the observation with `ID = 1`, the most recent non-missing value is 2002 in `Year5`, which (going backwards in years) is consecutively duplicated in `Year4` and `Year3` as well, and hence I would want `duplicated = TRUE`. The overall desired behavior is described below:

| ID | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year4 | Year5 | Year6 | duplicated_from_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | 2002 | NA | TRUE |
| 2 | 2002 | *NA* | 1001 | 1001 | 9999 | 9999 | FALSE |
| 3 | 2002 | *NA* | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | *NA* | TRUE |
| 4 | 3003 | 3003 | 3003 | NA | NA | NA | TRUE |
| 5 | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | 1001 | NA | NA | TRUE |
| 6 | 9999 | 9999 | 9999 | 1001 | 9999 | 9999 | FALSE |

I have attempted solutions with `rle()` which can count consecutive duplicates, although I am unable to determine how to condition on only counting duplicates beginning with the latest non-missing variable. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun I do not consider this as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `rle` by row - loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`), apply the run-length-encoding (`rle`) on the data (without the first column), extract the 'values' and corresponding 'lengths' from the `list` output.  Subset the values that are not `NA` (`!is.na`), and check the last element (`tail`) length is greater than or equal to 3

```
df$duplicated_from_end <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
    rl <- rle(x)
     v1 <- rl$values 
    l1 <- rl$lengths
    i1 <- !is.na(v1)
    tail(l1[i1], 1) >=3 })
```

-output

```
df$duplicated_from_end
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or slighly more compact would be to reverse arrangement of columns, and use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
apply(df[ncol(df):2], 1, \(x) table(rleid(x)[!is.na(x)])[1] >=3)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```